# foreach loop getting error while fetching perticular value

Tags: php, arrays

here is my code below,

```
<? foreach($goodsview as $key=>$value)
echo $value;
?>
```

above code works perfectly by displaying all the values in an array, now i need to fetch `perticular` value  using foreach loop itself,

`echo $value['myvalue'] ;`

but iam getting an error 
`Illegal string offset 'myvalue' 
how can we fix this?

Comment: Why is this tagged as _JavaScript_, _jQuery_, _HTML_ or _CSS_?

Comment: Illegal string offset occurs when the variable is not an array. Can you try `var_dump($value)` to check?

Comment: The above code does not work perfectly, unless you have both a `$values` and a `$value` variable... I assume you just want `$goodsview['myvalue'];` b.t.w.

Comment: Hi, I'm surprised you say your loop works - should the echo $values; not be echo $value;

Comment: just to clarify though, are you wanting to use the loop and highlight the entry with the key of 'myvalue' or the value 'myvalue'?

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$value` is not an array but a string. That's the reason why the error message is being displayed.

Without seeing the code there's not much to suggest. But in general, this is how foreach loops work:

Say your array structure is as follows.

```
Array
(
    [name] => Tom
    [gender] => Male
    [age] => 18
)
```

**To display all the elements**, i.e. *'Tom', 'Male', '18'*, you'd do something like this:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
     echo $arr[$key].'<br>';
}
```

**Output:**

```
Tom
Male
18
```

**To retrieve only a particular value:**

For example, if you want to retrieve the person's name, you can do:

```
echo $arr['name']; //Tom
echo $arr['gender']; //Male
echo $arr['age']; //18
```

Hope this clears up things for you! :)

Comment: @Friend: please update your question with the complete code so we may be in a better position to help you.

Answer (score 0):

`$value` holds the value in your `foreach` loop. It's the same as `$goodsview[$key]`. If you just want a single value then don't use the loop. `$goodsview['myvalue']` could hold a value if your Array looks like `$goodsview = array('myvalue' => 'This would be the value')`.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work, because `$values` does not exist

```
foreach($goodsview as $key => $value)
   echo $values;
```

This might work if `$value` is a string or number, etc, but not if it is a array.

```
foreach($goodsview as $key => $value)
   echo $value;
```

The string offset error refers to you accessing a string like an array, but the key you are using does not exist.

Let me explain.

```
$string = "Jake";
echo $sting[0]; //outputs 'J'
echo $sting[3]; //outputs 'e'
echo $sting['doom']; // will fail


$array = array("Jake", "doom"=>3);
echo $sting[0]; //outputs 'Jake'
echo $sting[3]; //will fail
echo $sting['doom']; // outputs 3
```

So `$value` is a string, not a array.

You can access your array like this too `$goodsview[$key]` which will give you the same as `$value`.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a shot in the dark but it looks like your maybe working on something like a loop to display options for a select element.
Normally you wouldn't waste time with a loop, if you were simply wanting a specific array element.

Does this give you any ideas:

```
<select name="myvalue">
<?php
foreach($goodsview as $key=>$value) {
  $seltxt='';
  // assume $myvalue is the previously posted value from the select
  // if the $key matches the posted $myvalue - mark this option as selected
  if (!strcmp($key,$myvalue)) $seltxt=' selected';
  echo "<option value=\"$key\"$seltxt>$value</option>\n";
}
?>
</select>
```

Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Well Let me Answer my own question, Actually  my array is a `single dimentional` so this method does not work

`echo $value['myvalue'] ;`

so we have to use

`echo $arr[$key]`

but it displays multiple elements as if it is running in foreachloop , so without using foreach loop we have to display the result something like

`echo $goodsview['myvalue']`

hope it will help someone in future if they come across with similar issue...Thank you all for responding to this question,